# d3.js multiple types of boxes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm getting a trouble with D3.js.

I tried to draw rects with different color for each name of dataset
(e.g. fixed_asset for blue, current_asset for red),
but only one type of boxes are drawn with following code.

Any suggestion is welcome.

```
    var dataset = [
    {  
       "fixed_asset":100,
       "current_asset":150,
       "equity":50,
       "long-term_liabilities":100,
       "short-term_liabilities":150,
       "revenue":400,
       "operating_income":150,
       "ebit":100,
       "ebt":50,
       "net_income":35
    },
    {  
       "fixed_asset":100,
       "current_asset":150,
       "equity":50,
       "long-term_liabilities":100,
       "short-term_liabilities":150,
       "revenue":400,
       "operating_income":150,
       "ebit":100,
       "ebt":50,
       "net_income":35
    }            
    ];

    var w = 400;
    var h = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h);

    var padding_left = 20;
    var padding_bottom = 30;

    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("fill", "blue")
       .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 100 + padding_left;})
       .attr("y", function(d){return h - padding_bottom - d["fixed_asset"];})
       .attr("width", 20)
       .attr("height", function(d){return d["fixed_asset"];});

    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("fill", "red")
       .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 100 + padding_left;})
       .attr("y", function(d){return h - padding_bottom - d["fixed_asset"] - d["current_asset"];})
       .attr("width", 20)
       .attr("height", function(d){return d["current_asset"];});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   ...

svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   ...
```

You are re-binding the data and computing the enter selection twice.  The first block works because the data is new (it's entered), the second block doesn't work though because it's the same data (nothing has entered).

You don't need to re-bind the data at all here.  Just keep a reference to the enter selection and append two rects:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
       var dataset = [
    {  
       "fixed_asset":100,
       "current_asset":150,
       "equity":50,
       "long-term_liabilities":100,
       "short-term_liabilities":150,
       "revenue":400,
       "operating_income":150,
       "ebit":100,
       "ebt":50,
       "net_income":35
    },
    {  
       "fixed_asset":100,
       "current_asset":150,
       "equity":50,
       "long-term_liabilities":100,
       "short-term_liabilities":150,
       "revenue":400,
       "operating_income":150,
       "ebit":100,
       "ebt":50,
       "net_income":35
    }            
    ];

    var w = 400;
    var h = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h);

    var padding_left = 20;
    var padding_bottom = 30;

    // keep reference to enter selection
    var eS = svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter();
    
    // first rect
    eS
       .append("rect")
       .attr("fill", "blue")
       .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 100 + padding_left;})
       .attr("y", function(d){return h - padding_bottom - d["fixed_asset"];})
       .attr("width", 20)
       .attr("height", function(d){return d["fixed_asset"];});
    
    // second rect
    eS
       .append("rect")
       .attr("fill", "red")
       .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * 100 + padding_left;})
       .attr("y", function(d){return h - padding_bottom - d["fixed_asset"] - d["current_asset"];})
       .attr("width", 20)
       .attr("height", function(d){return d["current_asset"];});
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Code works well with your indication,
and thanks for your thorough explanation.